# InputMethodService onCreateInputView not called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have a simple InputMethodService implementation:

```
class MyKeyboardView : InputMethodService() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        Timber.d("onCreate")
    }

    // Also tried the default implementation
    override fun onShowInputRequested(flags: Int, configChange: Boolean): Boolean {
        Timber.d("onShowInputRequested")

        return true
    }

    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        Timber.d("onCreateInputView")

        return KeyboardView(this)
    }

    private class KeyboardView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

        init {
            Timber.d("Init")
        }
    }

}
```

Input method is selected as current one.

Other methods like `onCreate`, `onShowInputRequested`, `onStartInputView` are called, but not `onCreateInputView`.

`onCreateInputView` is never called. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `onStartInputView`'s [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService#onStartInputView(android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo,%20boolean)):

> You are guaranteed that onCreateInputView() will have been called some time before this function is called.

So if you're seeing debug logs from this method, the create method must be called.

Try to override `onEvaluateInputViewShown` too and return true.